# how to remove ":" of cmake TARGET_OBJECTS, and use it in custom command

Tags: cmake

I want to use objs in COMMAND ld, but I cannot remove ";" in objs.

How can I remove ";"?

or have any other method to fix it?

## CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")

set(SOURCES
  lib1_public.h
  lib1_public.cpp
  lib.h
  lib.c)

add_library(objlib1 OBJECT ${SOURCES})

set(objs_list  "$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1>")
string(REPLACE ";" " " myobjs "${objs_list}")


add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  lib1_hidden.o
  COMMAND ld -r "${myobjs}" -o lib1.o
  COMMAND objcopy --localize-hidden lib1.o lib1_hidden.o
  COMMENT "Building mylib1.a")


add_library(mylib1 STATIC lib1_hidden.o)
```

## output

`[100%] Building mylib1.a
cd /home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1 && ld -r /home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1/CMakeFiles/objlib1.dir/lib1_public.cpp.o;/home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1/CMakeFiles/objlib1.dir/lib.c.o -o lib1.o`

Answer (score 4):

I believe what is missing here is the `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` option in `add_custom_command`. Try something along the lines of

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  lib1_hidden.o
  COMMAND ld -r $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1> -o lib1.o
  COMMAND objcopy --localize-hidden lib1.o lib1_hidden.o
  COMMENT "Building mylib1.a"
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Yup, this answer saved me from quite some trouble

Answer (score 0):

`$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1>` is a generator expression (aka "genex"), which means it only gets evaluated at *generate time:* after CMake has processed all its input files and has started generating the buildsystem. While CMake is still processing input, it's a literal string. Your `string(REPLACE)` therefore cannot have any effect, because the string `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1>` does not contain any semi-colons.

However, I don't think you actually need to remove them in any way. What causes them to appear on the command line is the fact that you're quoting the expansion of `myobjs` in the `COMMAND`, which means "treat this list after genex expansion as a single argument for the command." That's most likely not what you want. To pass the objects as one argument each, simply remove the quotes (and also the unneeded `string` command):

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")

set(SOURCES
  lib1_public.h
  lib1_public.cpp
  lib.h
  lib.c)

add_library(objlib1 OBJECT ${SOURCES})

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  lib1_hidden.o
  COMMAND ld -r $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1> -o lib1.o
  COMMAND objcopy --localize-hidden lib1.o lib1_hidden.o
  COMMENT "Building mylib1.a")

add_library(mylib1 STATIC lib1_hidden.o)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have use "COMMAND ld -r $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib1> -o lib1.o", but still met same error "cd /home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1 && ld -r /home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1/CMakeFiles/objlib1.dir/lib1_public.cpp.o;/home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1/CMakeFiles/objlib1.dir/lib.c.o -o lib1.o
/bin/sh: /home/yongle.xh/tmp/cmake_test/lib/lib1/CMakeFiles/objlib1.dir/lib.c.o: Permission denied"

Comment: @leon Weird. Especially since the "permission denied" error seems to be referencing the correct file. Can you try adding `add_dependencies(mylib1 objlib1)` to the CMakeList, to rule out concurrency issues?